# What is the expiry date for VS2010 Beta 2 products? (especially TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

With the final release date now unknown, what is the expiry date for the Beta 2 products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing TFS 2010 Beta 2 today gives an expiry date of June 30, 2010. I'm going to assume this is an absolute date and not one relative to when you install it, but I would be happy to hear anyone else's experience.

Comment: My VS2010 currently says "175 days remaining" which would also take it to 30 June.

Comment: It is indeed an absolute date.